# dockerice app laravel from exist repository

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I´m trying to create a container docker to my app, but it´s my first time. Always i use xampp, but i want to learn how to do this process. I´m reading any tutorial to do my container, but i can´t create it.

First, i´m building my file `Dockerfile` with this content:

```
#
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Image Setup
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
#

FROM php:8.1-fpm

# setup user as root
USER root

WORKDIR /var/www

# setup node js source will be used later to install node js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
RUN ["sh",  "./nodesource_setup.sh"]

# Install environment dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
 # gd
 && apt-get install -y build-essential  openssl nginx libfreetype6-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libwebp-dev zlib1g-dev libzip-dev gcc g++ make vim unzip curl git jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle locales libonig-dev nodejs  \
 && docker-php-ext-configure gd  \
 && docker-php-ext-install gd \
 # gmp
 && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libgmp-dev \
 && docker-php-ext-install gmp \
 # pdo_mysql
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring \
 # pdo
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo \
 # opcache
 && docker-php-ext-enable opcache \
 # exif
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && docker-php-ext-install sockets \
    && docker-php-ext-install pcntl \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath \
 # zip
 && docker-php-ext-install zip \
 && apt-get autoclean -y \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
 && rm -rf /tmp/pear/

# Copy files
COPY . /var/www

COPY ./docker/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/local.ini

COPY ./docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

RUN chmod +rwx /var/www

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    software-properties-common \
    npm
RUN npm install npm@latest -g && \
    npm install n -g && \
    n latest

# setup FE
RUN npm install

RUN npm rebuild node-sass

RUN npm run prod

# setup composer and laravel
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN composer install --working-dir="/var/www"

RUN composer dump-autoload --working-dir="/var/www"

RUN php artisan optimize

RUN php artisan route:clear

RUN php artisan route:cache

RUN php artisan config:clear

RUN php artisan config:cache

RUN php artisan view:clear

RUN php artisan view:cache

# remove this line if you do not want to run migrations on each build
RUN php artisan migrate --force

EXPOSE 80

RUN ["chmod", "+x", "post_deploy.sh"]

CMD [ "sh", "./post_deploy.sh" ]
# CMD php artisan serve --host=127.0.0.1 --port=9000
```

my `docker-compose.yml` have this content:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    
    # Application & web server
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        working_dir: /var/www
        volumes:
            - ./:/var/www
        depends_on:
            - "database"
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
    # Database
    database:
        image: mysql:8.0
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DB_DATABASE}
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}
            MYSQL_USER: ${DB_USERNAME}
        ports:
            - "33061:3306"
    # Database management
    pma:
        image: phpmyadmin:5.1
        environment:
            - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
            - PMA_HOST=${DB_HOST}
            - PMA_USER=${DB_USERNAME}
            - PMA_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
            - PMA_PORT=${DB_PORT}
        depends_on:
            - database
        ports:
            - 8888:8080
    # Mailing Server
    mailhog:
        image: mailhog/mailhog
        logging:
            driver: 'none'
        ports:
            - 1025:1025 
            - 8025:8025 

volumes:
    dbdata:
```

First time that execute this command to build container, fail and i did not know resolve. I do a `docker system prune -a` and now if i execute `docker build . -t my_container_name` return this:

```
[+] Building 30.1s (2/2) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                             docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.43kB                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.1-fpm                                                                                                                                                   30.0s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/php:8.1-fpm:
------
Dockerfile:7
--------------------
   5 |     #
   6 |     
   7 | >>> FROM php:8.1-fpm
   8 |     
   9 |     # setup user as root
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: php:8.1-fpm: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/php/manifests/8.1-fpm": proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 192.168.65.1:3128: i/o timeout
```

I don´t know that i´m doing wrong... If anybody can help me to create a container with my app from gitlab, with any tutorial or steps..., I'd be really grateful

Comment: the error message shows that docker is trying to pull the metadata for the specified image (docker.io/library/php:8.1-fpm).  this might be because of the internet connectivity/ proxy on the server or other issues , cant really pinpoint . can you try and  pull that image manually by running , docker pull docker.io/library/php:8.1-fpm

Comment: is the docker service running?

Comment: "failed to do request... proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 192.168.65.1:3128: i/o timeout"

Comment: @elemes thanks for your response. yes, if i execute this comand in terminal, response it´s ok and dowload it ok

Comment: @apokryfos yes, my service it´s running

Comment: the IP mentioned `192.168.65.1` is a local network IP (and port 3128 I don't actually recognize but may be a proxy port, the internet suggests it may be squid-http). Can you determine whether `192.168.65.1` is your local IP or something else and what service (if any) is using 3128 on that machine? You might have a proxy configured but not actually currently active.